# How can I read an SVG file and draw something in it?

Tags: python, file, svg

I want to read an SVG file in python 3.7. I would also like to draw several lines in this file, which contains a drawing. Drawing the lines in a newly created SVG file is no problem. One problem is opening an existing SVG file in Python, drawing in something new and then saving it again. Can someone help and tell me how I can open such a file and draw something in it? I was already looking for solutions on the internet but there was nothing that worked

Comment: check this? http://code.activestate.com/recipes/578123-draw-svg-images-in-python-python-recipe-enhanced-v/

Comment: SVG is an XML-based format. The standard library has an `xml` module.

Comment: there are special modules to generate SVG but I don't know if they can read it.

Comment: @gilch i am new in python what b wrestles me the xml. So could you explain to me how it works with xml?

Comment: "_Drawing the lines in a newly created SVG file is no problem._" How did you do this?

Comment: i use a python lib named PYX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i use a python lib named PYX

From the [PyX Manual](https://pyx-project.org/manual/svgfile.html):

> With the help of the `svgfile.svgfile` class, you can easily embed another SVG
> file in your canvas, thereby scaling, aligning the content at discretion. The
> most simple example looks like
>
> ```
> from pyx import *
> c = canvas.canvas()
> c.insert(svgfile.svgfile(0, 0, "file.svg"))
> c.writeSVGfile("output")
> ```

Comment: Thank you for your help. How do you know that? Is there documentation about the library?

Comment: Yes, just click the link, and you're in the middle of the documentation. :-)

Comment: oh sorry i dont see it :)

Comment: can you help me again? If I want to output a PDF in PYX, the error "cannot output unparsed SVG to PDF" occurs. However, if I set the parsed to True in the .insert, my pdf file looks strange because it randomly draws new lines and curves

Comment: I'm not sure I can help there - perhaps if you posted a new question. You can then leave a link here.

Comment: today i cant post a new question...i ask u later if ist okay?

Comment: @Mephisto_08 - Of course - and then you're asking not only me, but an army of experts. :-)